# How to combine resultset of three queries on same table horizantaly group by and order by

Tags: sql

1st query and result

```
select distinct USERID, min(JOBDATE) AS 'DATA_INSERT_DATE', FILENAME, LOTNO, count(*) as 'TOTAL' 
from CF10_BULK_RCPT_RMK  
group by USERID, FILENAME, LOTNO  
order by USERID, FILENAME, LOTNO

| USERID  | DATA_INSERT_DATE  | FILENAME |LOTNO| TOTAL |
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:14 PM | File3.xls|  3  | 4239  |
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:39 PM | File2.xls|  2  | 5     | 
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:52 PM | File1.xls|  1  | 4498  |
```

2nd query and result

```
select count(1) AS 'SUCCESS' 
from CF10_BULK_RCPT_RMK 
where STATUS = 'Completed'
group by LOTNO
order by LOTNO

|SUCCESS|
|4239   |
|  5    |
| 4498  |
```

3rd query and result

```
select count(1) AS 'FAILED' 
from CF10_BULK_RCPT_RMK 
where STATUS = 'Failed'
group by LOTNO
order by LOTNO

|FAILED |
```

I want to combine result of all queries horizontally as

```
| USERID  | DATA_INSERT_DATE  | FILENAME |LOTNO| TOTAL |SUCCESS|FAILED |
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:14 PM | File3.xls|  3  | 4239  |4239   |  0    |    
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:39 PM | File2.xls|  2  | 5     |  5    |  0    |  
| 5023294 | 09/30/15 07:52 PM | File1.xls|  1  | 4498  | 4498  |  0    |
```

Comment: You can remove DISTINCT from query #1, since the GROUP BY's result already is distinct.

Comment: Still struggling? Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about to add `CASE` in following?

```
select distinct USERID,min(JOBDATE) AS 
'DATA_INSERT_DATE',FILENAME,LOTNO,count(*) as 'TOTAL',
SUM(case when STATUS = 'Completed' then count(1) end) as 'SUCCESS',
SUM(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then count(1) end) as 'FAILED'
from CF10_BULK_RCPT_RMK  
group by USERID,FILENAME,LOTNO  
order by USERID,FILENAME,LOTNO
```

Comment: above query gives error : Column 'CF10_BULK_RCPT_RMK.STATUS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.